# class not found with composer autoloader

Tags: php, composer-php

I have this in my `composer.json`

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.0",
        "alchemy/zippy": "^0.4.8",
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.1",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
        "graham-campbell/exceptions": "^10.0",
        "intervention/image": "^2.4",
        "intervention/imagecache": "^2.3",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^5.5",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "^3.3"
    },
    "files": [
        "vendor/redbutton/text-image-alpha/vendor/autoload.php"
    ],
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "^2.1",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    }
}
```

The php files for my package are in a laravel installation:
`/vendor/redbutton/text-image-alpha/src/`

When I try to call a file I get the message:

```
Class 'Class 'RedButton\TextImageAlpha\TextImageAlpha' not found' not found
```

I use this to try and call the class:

```
$image     = new \RedButton\TextImageAlpha\TextImageAlpha( 'some string' );
```

The file in `/vendor/redbutton/text-image-alpha/src/TextImageAlpha.php` looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace RedButton\TextImageAlpha;

use RedButton\TextImageAlpha\Exceptions;
use RedButton\Tools\Objects;


/**
 * TextImageAlpha class convert a text to image.
 *
 * @author Tomas Rathouz <trathouz at gmail.com>
 */
class TextImageAlpha
{
   // lots of code
}
```

This is my first composer package and I don't really have an idea of what is going wrong here. Could someone please explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What namespace do you have in your class file (`src/TextImageAlpha.php`)? You also need to end with a slash when defining the path in composer.json: `"src/"`. Don't forget to do a `composer dump-autoload` after you've updated the composer.json file.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I've updated my question. I've added the `/` to the src path but that didn't help.

Comment: Did you manually create the folder `/vendor/redbutton/text-image-alpha/src/` and all the files or did you add them using `composer require`? If you manually added them, the "main" (top) composer file doesn't know about it. Composer doesn't automatically include all files/folders in `/vendor`. You need to tell the "main" composer file to use the package composer file.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I've created it manually, how do I tell the "main" composer file to include my folder? Should I put it in `require` or somewhere else?

Comment: If you added it manually, try to add `"files": ["vendor/redbutton/text-image-alpha/vendor/autoload.php"]` to the main composer files `"autoload"`-part and run a `composer dump-autoload`. That will tell composer to load that autoloader as well.

Comment: I've run `composer dump-autoload` in the `image-text-alpha` directory. It now has an autoload and I've added `"files": ["vendor/redbutton/text-image-alpha/vendor/autoload.php"]` to my main `composer.json` file. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you also run a `composer dump-autoload` in the main folder?

Comment: Yes I did run it as well in the main directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156811/discussion-between-sheperdoffire-and-magnus-eriksson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news. I've looked at your [package at Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/redbuttondevelopers/text-image-alpha/) and you're doing it right in its [`composer.json`](https://bitbucket.org/redbuttondevelopers/text-image-alpha/src/b6094dbd4a01f6b9789fe7916ba48216d7b40f71/composer.json?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#composer.json-28):

### Drop unnecessary code from `composer.json`

I've noticed in pasted `composer.json` there is **manual adding of some vendor file**.

```
"files": [
    "vendor/redbutton/text-image-alpha/vendor/autoload.php"
],
```

`/vendor` nested in `/vendor` doesn't make sense as it might duplicate autoloading and break it.

Also I don't see `redbutton/text-image-alpha` in `require` section, where it should be.

### How to add package the right way?

**To install your package just call composer**:

```
composer require redbutton/text-image-alpha
```

And that's it.

It should appear in `require` section in `composer.json`. Composer will autoload it by rules in **`composer.json` of the package** - [here](https://bitbucket.org/redbuttondevelopers/text-image-alpha/src/b6094dbd4a01f6b9789fe7916ba48216d7b40f71/composer.json?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#composer.json-28).

---

#### Test

I've tried following code and class is found correctly:

```
<?php 

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$image = new \RedButton\TextImageAlpha\TextImageAlpha('some string');
var_dump($image);
```

Having `composer.json`:

```
{
    "require": {
        "redbutton/text-image-alpha": "^1.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: I was banging my head against the table for days... `new \PATH\TO\CLASS` did it! I had included `autoload.php` properly but my class still wasn't showing up, and now I know why. Thanks!